# Where is the auto save option in Microsoft Office 2016 for Word and Power Point?

Tags: ms-office

Yesterday, I managed to lose a couple of hours of work, because I had forgotten to save my file.

Now I wanted to enable the auto save option for Power Point and Word, which I thought would also be available in Office 2016, but I can't find it. Also, googling only brought up guides for Word 2011, which don't work with Office 2016.

Could some one of you please point me to the correct option?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There is no Office 2013 for Mac.

Comment: I found the option to modify the autosave: PowerPoint > Preferences > Output and Sharing - Save

Comment: @Tabea congrats on finding your own answer!  Why not post it as a proper answer to your question for others who may have the same issue? See [Can I answer my own question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the help section.

Answer (score 4):

This is not auto-save however.  This simply sets the interval at which Excel will generate an auto-save file should there be a crash.  If you close without saving, this file is immediately deleted.  If the crash doesn't meet Microsoft's definition of a crash, the file is deleted.  If you don't open Excel properly the next time, the auto-recover won't show and the file will be deleted.

What most people want, myself included, is a true autosave.  Once you create a file, name it and save it once, it will continue to save it again at a set interval.  Microsoft does not offer this option.

Answer (score 2):

The Autosave function only works if you have a file saved to OneDrive or SharePoint Online.

Comment: Here's the link to Microsoft Support to support this answer: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-autosave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5

Answer (score 1):

To access Autosave for Word in Windows 10...
Open a Word document, click "File" then "options" then "save". Check "Save AutoRecover information every X minutes."

You will be able to decide how often it will save.

Then click OK/Save at bottom right to make sure it saves your new preference.

Comment: You can repeat this process in PowerPoint and in Excel.

Comment: OP is asking for Office on Mac which is different as per the comments

Answer (score 1):

Word 2016 doesn't have a true autosave function, as in save file every x minutes (I can see some negatives to this anyways) but it does save files you didn't save before closing if you tell it to.  Under file, options, save...in the same location Save AutoRecover information every x minutes is, there is also the option "Keep the last autosaved version if I close without saving" option.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a Macro in a template though you would have to allow it to run and start it going each time you opened the file or maybe assigning StartTimer to a button on the Quick Access toolbar.  Perhaps something like this:

Sub StartTimer()

' StartTimer Macro

```
Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), Name:="LazySave"
```

End Sub

Sub LazySave()

' Save document and restart timer

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Save

StartTimer
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For reference with Excel: Excel > Preferences > Save > "Save Autorecover info every _ minutes"